# Very slow eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query in one of my controller in my Laravel controllers that looks like this,

```
        $project = new Project;
        $me = ResourceServer::getOwnerId();

        $my_projects = Project::ManagedByMe($me)
        ->OwnedByOrganisationIAmIn($me)
        ->IAmACollaborator($me)
        ->NoArchived()
        ->get(array(
            'projects.id',
            'projects.name', 
            'projects.description',
            'projects.total_cost',
            'projects.sales_person',
            'projects.slug',
            'projects.uri_hash',
            'projects.client_id',
            'projects.start_date',
            'projects.finish_date',
            'projects.organisation_id',
            'projects.locked_by',
            'projects.created_at',
            'projects.status',
            'projects.owner_id',
            'projects.user_id',
            'projects.archived_at'
        ));

        $my_projects->load('projectmanager');
        $my_projects->load('clients');
        $my_projects->load('organisations')->load('organisations.users');
        $my_projects->load('collaborators');
        $my_projects->load('status');
        $my_projects->load('notifications')->load('notifications.user');

        $my_projects->load(array('projectview'=>function($query){

            $query->where('users.id','=',ResourceServer::getOwnerId());

        }));
```

It returns 898 rows of data, and takes over a minute to execute. I am using scopes in the query, that look like this,

```
public function scopeManagedByMe($query, $user_id) {
    $query->distinct();
    $query->leftJoin('project_managers', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_managers.project_id');
    $query->where('project_managers.user_id', '=', $user_id);
}

public function scopeOwnedByOrganisationIAmIn($query, $user_id) {
    $query->leftJoin('organisations', 'projects.organisation_id', '=', 'organisations.id');
    $query->leftJoin('organisation_user', 'organisations.id', '=', 'organisation_user.organisation_id');
    $query->orWhere('organisation_user.user_id', '=', $user_id);
}

public function scopeIAmACollaborator($query, $user_id) {
    $query->leftJoin('collaborators', 'projects.id', '=', 'collaborators.project_id');
    $query->orWhere('collaborators.user_id', '=', $user_id);
}

public function scopeNoArchived($query) {
    $query->orWhere('projects.archived_at', '=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
    $query->whereNull('projects.deleted_at');
}
```

and the SQL that is actually run looks like this,

```
    select distinct `projects`.`id`, 
                `projects`.`name`, 
                `projects`.`description`, 
                `projects`.`total_cost`, 
                `projects`.`sales_person`, 
                `projects`.`slug`, `projects`.`uri_hash`, 
                `projects`.`client_id`, 
                `projects`.`start_date`, `projects`.`finish_date`, 
                `projects`.`organisation_id`, 
                `projects`.`locked_by`, `projects`.`created_at`, 
                `projects`.`status`, 
                `projects`.`owner_id`, 
                `projects`.`user_id`, 
                `projects`.`archived_at` 
from `projects` 
left join `project_managers` on `projects`.`id` = `project_managers`.`project_id` 
left join `organisations` on `projects`.`organisation_id` = `organisations`.`id` 
left join `organisation_user` on `organisations`.`id` = `organisation_user`.`organisation_id` 
left join `collaborators` on `projects`.`id` = `collaborators`.`project_id` 
where `projects`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `project_managers`.`user_id` = ? or `organisation_user`.`user_id` = ? 
or `collaborators`.`user_id` = ? or `projects`.`archived_at` = ? 
and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null
```

What I am trying to do, is select all the projects that I belong to, either by virtue that I am in an organisation that owns a project, I am project manager of the project or a collaborator of the project.

Comment: And the question is .... ? ;-)

Comment: Have you tested the query on its own?

Comment: What does `explain select...` says for the query ?

Comment: The query on it's own in sequel pro takes 280 ms to run and return the 898 rows of data. @violator667 the question why is it slow on a the web platform?

Comment: The answer is: we don't know. The suggestion to obtain the answer was posted by @AbhikChakraborty - use `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see what MySQL does. I also have no idea what sequel pro is, where you tested the data (is it locally or on a dev machine) and many such details. I'm willing to bet that your problem is most likely default MySQL configuration on your production. It could also be that the query executes fast enough but the program you use to display the data is slow.

Comment: all indexes properly setted?

Answer (score 0):

At first set indexes on join-condition fields:

```
`projects`.`id`
`projects`.`organisation_id`
`project_managers`.`project_id` 
`organisations`.`id` 
`organisation_user`.`organisation_id` 
`collaborators`.`project_id`
```

if some of them are not setted.

Then update your query execution time in question subject.